# Add share button to app page

Tags: button, save, facebook-iframe

I have created my app which just shows an image. Below the image I would like to invite people to Share by displaying a Share button. If they do share, the image is replaced by another image. I have worked out how to display the Share button but I can't work out how to display the next image if they have shared.  I'm new to app development and will appreciate any assistance. Maybe there is a tutorial somewhere that I have been unable to find.

Answer (score 0):

By sharing do you mean liking?  If so, then search for fan-gate.

Here's a great tutorial on it: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBBnrtG0hAw